# Is there an 'Onload' sort of a signal for QMainWindow?

Tags: dialog, pyqt

PyQt noob here.

I need to call a dialog window as soon as the main window is loaded.
I also need the main window to be displayed in the background when this dialog is shown on top of it.

So, I'm looking for a 'onload' sort of a signal for the main window to call the function which in turn calls the dialog. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [QWidget.showEvent](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#showEvent) for your QMainWindow to achieve the same effect. However, you need to keep track of whether it is the first time the window is shown or not since that method will be called every time the window is displayed after being hidden. Then use a [modal](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdialog.html#details) [QDialog](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdialog.html) so that the main window is shown in the background, but not enabled.